# Where can I find a jQuery article rotator / carousel / slider?

Tags: php, jquery, slider, carousel, rotator

I want to make an article rotator similar to http://www.vmagazine.com/
And I want to use jQuery.

I know there are carousels like [jCarousel](http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/) and [jQuery Carousel](http://thomlx.free.fr/jquery/jquery_carousel.htm).
There is also the [Coda-Slider](http://jqueryfordesigners.com/demo/coda-slider.html), but I don't fint it very elegant.

Can anyone suggest a good jQuery method / script for having an article carousel?

I don't want to use MooTools, Prototype etc. since I'm already using jQuery.

Any suggestions anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out Flowplayer's Scrollable PLugin:  http://flowplayer.org/tools/scrollable/index.html#demos

I haven't used it, but I believe you can set it to auto-scroll.

Comment: How would you go about adding paging below image? Like [1] [2] [3] and so forth?

Comment: I believe you would put your panes html above your tabs. It looks like the navigation and the panes would work independently of each other. Like I said, I've never used the scrollable plugin, but I have used the overlay one.